# Erro no dtype na junção de arquivos

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Preciso juntar vários arquivos csv, onde as colunas são float. Fiz um pequeno código, mas a saída das colunas estão em str, então tentei adicionar o formato de saída dos dados, mas está saindo o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: 'dtype' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Onde será que está o erro? Segue o código:

```
# Abre o arquivo redacao.txt para escrita:
with open("/home/mayna/Downloads/Leo/uniao.csv", "w", dtype=float) as file:

# Percorre a lista de arquivos a serem lidos:
    for temp in ["/home/mayna/Downloads/Leo/B116353_2018_FILTRADO.csv", "/home/mayna/Downloads/Leo/B116354_2018_FILTRADO.csv"]:

        # Abre cada arquivo para leitura:
        with open(temp, "r") as t:

            # Escreve no arquivo o conteúdo:
            file.writelines(t)
```

Obrigada!

Comment: qual versão do python está usando?

Comment: Estou utilizando a versão 3.7.3

Answer (score 1):

A função `open()` não tem o parâmetro `dtype`, como a mensagem está indicando. (Fonte: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open)

Você pode ler o dado como string mesmo, e realizar a conversão apenas na hora de usar o valor, utilizando  função `float()`.